# Position the caret in Bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, css-position

I want to modify the Bootstrap dropdown button to move the caret out of the calculations for button width after padding. In other words, I want to "center" the text in the button by providing equal padding on each side, but have the dropdown caret still to the right.

I've tried several things, including using relative positioning on the button (didn't work at all) and absolute positioning (partially worked but lost vertical positioning/centering).

Additionally, there are several things making this trickier:

- Some dropdowns have no text, only an icon
- Icon is added with Font Awesome (uses `:before` element/selector)

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div class="btn-group"
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle fa fa-download">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default fa fa-envelope"></button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
        More <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

[image: Sample Image]

As you can see in the "correct" example, the caret is no longer affecting the width of the button (but is "inside" the button's padding, shown by the pink lines). Does anyone know how this is possible? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to @Dekel for the answer (slightly adapted it to suit my needs and work for both types [those with only icons and those with text]):

```
/* I also removed the space in the HTML before the caret, which is where "top" comes in */
.btn.fa .caret {
    left: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
.btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
    right: -12px;
}
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/UnaviaMedia/pen/qqYgqX)

Comment: Can you provide an example? (jsfiddle/snippet/codepen)

Comment: @Dekel Thanks, I forgot to add it to original message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost sure this is what you are looking for:

```
.btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 1px);
}
```

Please check and let me know.
The second block of buttons is without the caret as part of the width-calculations. I added another class to the container to set these specific values:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aBGrWW

Comment: Right now this seems to be working for me, thanks! I removed the space added in HTML and instead used `left:` to compensate (cleaner).

    `.btn.fa .caret {
        left: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 1px);
    }
    .btn .caret {
        right: -12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50% - 1px);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `position: absolute;` to the caret it will no longer affect the text's position. You can then use `right` and `top` properties to position the caret where you want it to display inside the padding.

Example:

```
.btn .caret {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Note: Make sure the button is anything but position: static so that the caret is anchored to the button (i.e. make it `position: relative;`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that `top: calc(50% - 1px);` is cleaner personally (and more responsive) than `top: 10px;`, especially if we change the button/line height/padding in the future.